# querySelectorAll() print textcontent of all nodes

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, phantomjs

this is the code i am using to get all text content from webpage. yet its not working and I do not know what i am doing wrong.

```
<tr style="color:#000000" class="odd">
  <td style="padding:5px 5px 5px 10px" align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="cards[]" id="card_278002" value="278002"></td>
  <td align="center">411756</td>
  <td align="center">Sherrie</td>
  <td align="center">89852</td>
</tr>
```

and thats my Js code :

```
function get42() {
    return document.querySelectorAll('tr>td').textContent;
}
console.log(page.evaluate(get42));
```

Output : `null` .. what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use `document.querySelectorAll` like that. It returns a `NodeList`. You have to take the `textContent` from each Node yourself.

Longer way:

```
function get42() {
    var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td'),
        result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        result.push(tds[i].textContent);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or Shorter:

```
function get42() {
    var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(tds, function(t) { return t.textContent; });
}
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cu46gs8r/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much ! yet this map thing is so hard for my brain  to understand.

Comment: _“You have to take the textContent from each Node yourself”_ – or simply get the `textContent` of the parent element … (but then you might need to strip/normalize the whitespace, granted.)

Comment: @victory No problem. That `map` example is a bit more complex, because it's borrowing the map function from `Array` (since `NodeList` does not have one). Nothing wrong with using the longer way. For an easier to understand `map` example consider an array (which has map built in): `[1,2,3].map(function(num) { return num * 2 });` returns `[2, 4, 6]` ...basically you're mapping a function to every element of the array. This example is just taking that value and multiplying it by 2. Hope that helps!

Comment: helped me as well! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the map example! I was looking for a oneliner, like jquery's `text()` but without jquery and this is the closest I think.